# Can we apply Fleming's the right hand rule to AC generated magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Since AC current changes its direction and magnitude over a period, how can I determine the direction of current in a wire, thus find the direction of magnetic field and force?

Comment: Hi welcome to PSE. Please clarify what would mean by right hand rule. What are you trying to calculate (there are in fact many right hand rules)?

Comment: According to Wiki, "Fleming's Right-hand Rule (for generators) shows the direction of induced current when a conductor attached to a circuit moves in a magnetic field." If you want to know the direction of magnetic field produced by a current, you need a different rule.

Comment: If AC current doesn't have a direction like DC does, then yes I am asking that, how do we know the direction of magnetic field produced by such current.